# SQL in Access Error using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

Some 25 years ago I learned SQL. This doesn't help me now:)

In Access I have a very simple query:

```
SELECT Bank.BankID, Bank.BankName, Address.StreetName, Address.StreetNumber, Address.ZipCode, Address.City, Bank.TransactionFile
FROM Bank 
LEFT JOIN Address ON Bank.[BankID] = Address.[BankID]
```

Now I want to exclude duplicate records so I use the DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Bank.BankID, Bank... etc
```

However, I do not want the TransactionFile to be part of the DISTINCT selection, in order to get the data I want.
So I thought to use the GROUP BY statement instead:

```
SELECT Bank.BankID, Bank.BankName, Address.StreetName, Address.StreetNumber, Address.ZipCode, Address.City, Bank.TransactionFile
FROM Bank LEFT JOIN Address ON Bank.[BankID] = Address.[BankID]
GROUP BY Bank.BankID, Bank.BankName, Address.StreetName, Address.StreetNumber, Address.ZipCode, Address.City
```

But now I get the errormessage "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'TransactionFile' as part of an aggregate function".
If I only GROUP BY Bank.BankID I get the same message on Bank.BankName.

What am I missing here??
Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to handle the transaction-file? If everything else is distinct and you have 3 transaction files, do you want to see one line or three?

Comment: Just the one line. I want to disregard the TransactionFile completely.

Comment: I want to see every unique line, and for those records that differ, I want to see the TransactionFile data.

Comment: then remove the field from the query?

Comment: I need the data.. "Bank X, Address 1, Transaction Old" on one line, and on the other line "Bank X, Address 2, Transaction New". I have some 2000 records with Old and New Transaction and I only want to see the records where the data differs, regardless the value in Transaction. And when the records are different I want to see the value of the Transaction (Old and New).

Comment: How do you identify old and new? is it date based?

Answer (score 1):

All columns not in the `GROUP BY` need to be in aggregation functions.  So, either remove `Bank.TransactionFile` or use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT Bank.BankID, Bank.BankName, Address.StreetName, Address.StreetNumber,
       Address.ZipCode, Address.City, MAX(Bank.TransactionFile)
FROM Bank LEFT JOIN
     Address
     ON Bank.[BankID] = Address.[BankID]
GROUP BY Bank.BankID, Bank.BankName, Address.StreetName, Address.StreetNumber,
         Address.ZipCode, Address.City;
```

Comment: ah okay... Any solution for my problem? I want to see the TransactionFile included in the line when the rest of the data has differences

Comment: @Karin . . . I think you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.